# Connecting to an external GitLab repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am trying to clone an external repository from my local machine in Git bash on Windows.

I run these commands from an empty folder on my Windows machine:

```
$ git clone https://git.company.org/projectowner/theproject.git
Cloning into 'TheProject'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.company.org/projectowner/theproject.git/'
```

I believe it is HTTPS from what I remember and have cleared my Window credentials handler both in the credentials manager and in the git unset command.

Still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it matter if the projectowner is an inactive user who is no longer at the company too

Comment: "Access denied" seems pretty straightforward: you don't have permission, e.g., you don't have the right password or access token or Yubikey or whatever it is that's required to allow *you* to *read* that repository. (Also, decide whether you're asking about Git, which is one thing, or GItHub, which is a different thing, or GitLab, which is a *third* different thing. Permissions on GitHub are not permissions on GitLab, and neither has anything to do with Git, which doesn't handle access control in the first place.)

Comment: It seems some credential manger still works as it does not ask for the username and password. If it's hosted in gitlab, try `git clone https://oauth2@git.company.org/projectowner/theproject.git` and see if it asks for the password or token.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the lack of credential helper:

```
git config --show-scope --show-origin credential.helper
```

Check your environment variables for anything related to `GIT`.
And check if you have any resource file (`~/.curlrc`, `~/.git-credentials`) which might store credentials used by hTTPS.

If the remote hosting service is setup correctly, it must prompt you for your credentials.